# Optimize DELETE FROM with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, optimization, where-clause, sql-delete

How can I optimize this query ?

```
DELETE FROM item WHERE id = 1002;
DELETE FROM item WHERE id = 1003;
DELETE FROM item WHERE id = 102232;
DELETE FROM item WHERE id = 12322;
```

It is a way out ?

```
DELETE FROM item WHERE id = 1002 OR id = 1003 OR id = 102232 OR id = 12322;
```

I need Expert's mind very much!

Comment: how many rows are you trying to delete? 1000, 10,000?

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM item WHERE id IN (1002,1003,102232,12322)
```

It's simpler but what do you mean by optimized (faster ?)

Comment: Well if you got an index on your id, it should be fast enough with one query. You could easily test which one is faster by creating/deleting a lot of lines.